# Email is not an Apple ID or email is being used as an Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id

I am getting these errors when trying to login with my mother's email.

Can it be a bug in Apple?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to create an apple id. The email you are trying to use already exist as an apple id so you need to create a new apple id (using a different email address) or try to login with that one. If you can't recall the password click on "forgot password?"

Comment: I did what you said. One form says this email is not an apple id, one says email is used as an Apple Id.